# Is using an id as a business value an anti-pattern

Tags: c#, database, anti-patterns

With the risk of being labeled off-topic I am going to ask it any way :-)

I recently joined a new development team and they do have a habit of doing the following. While I have always considered it an anti pattern I just find out that I can't explain why. So, I am just curious to get your opinions.

Let consider the following situation: You have an invoice application, when a new invoice needs to be created, it has to get a new unique invoice number (like INV0001). Of course, it will be stored in the DB, in a table having an auto increment field 'id'. So, just generate the Number from the id.

```
class Invoice{
     [Key]
     int Id { get; set;}

     string Number => String.Concat("INV", this.Id.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));
}
```

I have always (blindly) obeyed the rule "**don't use an id as a business value**". but I can't really motivate it.

Comment: i agree, best serial numbers can contain more information

Comment: Blindly obeying rules is the root of all evil. There are no universal rules that apply to all programming and don't let anyone tell you otherwise. Basically it depends..

Comment: I would say that it depends on whether you want these numbers to be globally unique - and also, whether you want to easily move the data around - I would seriously be tempted away from using the ID as a business value

Comment: By bookkeeping law(in most of the countries) invoice number should be running number without any gaps. So using database `Id` for this will lead to possibility to have those gaps and so violating that rule

Comment: @Fabio what gap? can you give an example?

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), some argue that a surrogate should not have semantic meaning. Personally, I think it doesn't matter. the point of an identity column is to provide an automated unique value.

Comment: @LeiYang (cc @Fabio): If you create a record in an transaction which will be rolledback, the next record will not reuse the id.

Comment: @Liam, let me rephrase: I have always consider it a best practice that felt intuitively correct.

Comment: @Liam, _Blindly obeying rules is the root of all evil._ - do not tell this to younger developers ;)

Answer (score 2):

> don't use an id as a business value

You can apply same explanation which used for motivating of *Separation of concerns*.

If in business logic code you are using features of implementation details of `Id`, for example generated by database, this mean that your business logic depend on database implementation.

`Id` have one responsibility - provide unique value, by which you can identify entity and link it with other related entities. So in your business logic you can use `Id` value only for equality conditions.

For example if you have `Id` of type `integer` generated by database.
And you have somewhere in the business logic condition

```
if (Id == 0)
{
    return "new";
}
```

Your business logic will depend on `Id` implementation (type). Which mean you can use only `Id` of value `integer` and can not change it to `Guid` for example.